# Script file is created to send junk mails

Tags: ubuntu, email, php5, malware, joomla

I have installed Joomla 3.3.6 on my ubnutu server 15.04 on cloud. I have noticed some script file created automatically which is sending some junk mail randomly. I have installed maldetect to check for malware.

Recent file detect was `/var/www/html/joomla-test/libraries/joomla/observable/ini3.php`

I have deleted this file now. But this type of script file created frequently. How to find from where this file created and delete permanently.

Do I need to move code to different server to get rid of this?.

Edit:

It is related to Joomla plugins I suspect. If we move our code to new server or install joomla again and install all necessary plugins and theme again same script might be created again.

Comment: If you move the same code versions to the new server, it will likely be compromised there as well.

Comment: then what procedure we can follow to solve this?

Comment: Read the duplicate question. You have a software vulnerability somewhere. That needs to be found and fixed before this issue will go away.